# How Do I Create An Array With Multiple Variables In Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to iOS development, and for some reason I can't figure out how to do this even though I realize it has to be simple. I want to create a collection with 2 string values. For instance:

```
var firstName = "Bob"
var lastName = "Smith"
```

So the first index would contain ("Bob", "Smith") and so one for each first and last name I want to add to the collection. What object do I use? I tried a dictionary but it seems you have to add your values to that up front, and I need to add my later on programmatically.

Comment: You can modify a dictionary at any time if it's declared as a var: `var dict = [:]` `dict["x"] = 4`

Comment: You are asking the questions and didn't read Apple Swift Book. There it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a dictionary but I'd create a Person struct that contains a firstName and a lastName and put those into an array.

```
struct Person {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
}

var firstName = "Bob"
var lastName = "Smith"

var array = [Person(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName)]
```

It also has the benefit of being able to access the parts using `.firstName` and `.lastName`

```
array[0].firstName
```

As opposed to a dictionary that that requires a string

```
array[0]["firstName"]
```

Answer (score 2):

To create an array with only string you use

`var shoppingList: [String] = ["Eggs", "Milk"]`

And to add to the end of the array (push) you use

`shoppingList.append("Bread")`

Answer (score 1):

The struct way is preferred, but if you want to do something more similar to the initial request you could do an array of tuples